# What does "in a sandpaper-dry kind of way" mean?

Tags: meaning

> He was the quintessential newsman: cynical at times, but unrelentingly
>   curious and full of life, and often hilariously funny in a
>   sandpaper-dry kind of way.

Could you tell me please what it means?

Does it mean:

> His laughting made noise like lustle of rubbing a surface with sandpaper.

The fuller text:

> When I began my career in journalism—I was a reporter at a national
>   magazine in those days—there was a man I’ll call Claus Schmidt. He was
>   in his mid-fi fties, and to my impressionable eyes, he was the
>   quintessential newsman: cynical at times, but unrelentingly curious
>   and full of life, and often hilariously funny **in a sandpaper-dry kind
>   of way**. He churned out hard-hitting cover stories and features with a
>   speed and elegance I could only dream of. It always astounded me that
>   he was never promoted to managing editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It refers to ["dry" or "deadpan" humor](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Dry+humor) : *marked by a fixed air of seriousness or calm detachment.*

By using "sandpaper-dry" instead of just "dry", the author tried to convey that the newsman's sense of humor was not just a little dry, it was very dry and maybe "[gritty](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gritty)" which is also used to describe humor (in the sense of *having strong qualities of tough uncompromising realism*).

Here's another example of the same usage from [Paste](https://www.drawnandquarterly.com/press/2016/12/paste-25-best-comics-2016) *The 25 Best Comics of 2016*:

> They’re silly, but in a serious manner, where a sandpaper-dry delivery renders the absurd amusing.

Answer (score 1):

"Dry" means he is funny in a specific way, which is quite hard to explain, actually. It is a fast, unexpected and often witty response.

Answer (score 0):

I would not say it means dry, but rather slightly grating.

Comment: I think this could be improved by expanding on your explanation, in non-abstract terms. This isn't clarifying the mistake in OP's understanding - the description is not about his laughter but about his humor.